# How to disable DataGrid automatic resize

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

My `<DataGrid>` control keeps stretching vertically when I load it with too many items.

How can I keep its original size unchanged? I also have `SizeToContent="Height"` attribute set on parent `<Window>`.

Little demo (height should remain same like it was empty):

[image: demo]

Very simplified XAML snippet which should help you recognize the problem:

```
<Window SizeToContent="Height">
<Grid>
<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/> <!-- First column -->
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/> <!-- Second column -->
</Grid.ColumnDefintions>

<DataGrid Grid.Column="0">...</DataGrid> <!-- Should resize to second column and not get longer when items are added on runtime --> 
<TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Height="500"/>
</Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: When you remove `SizeToContent` your window should stop resizing to accommodate `DataGrid`

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you delete the "SizeToContent" property for the window?

Otherwise Set a fixed size/height for the datagrid.

```
Height="200"
```

Comment: When I remove SizeToContent property the window gets little too long. I don't want to set fixed height for DataGrid, because it's inside a Grid and should fluently resize to height of second column on the right (not visible on my demo).

Comment: Ok. If you Set the height to auto !? Sorry for this try and error but i cant rebuild this problem right now...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<DataGrid VerticalAlignment="Top" />
```